# How do I perform a redirect in Concrete 5.7?

Tags: redirect, concrete5, concrete5-5.7

What's the correct way of performing a server-side redirect in custom Concrete5 code (5.7+)?

Answer (score 3):

I discovered this is the best way:

```
(new RedirectResponse('/URL-HERE'))->send();          // 302 temporary
(new RedirectResponse('/URL-HERE', 301))->send();     // 301 permanent
```

You should be able to call this from (almost) anywhere within the app and not worry about namespaces since it has an alias in `/concrete/config/app.php`.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution would be as follows:

```
$response = \Redirect::to('/URL-HERE');
$response->send();
exit;
```

or

```
return \Redirect::to('/URL-HERE')->send();
```

Sidenote: The url provided must not be absolute. For example: `'/dashboard/reports/logs'`